# Unable To Get Twitch API OAuth For PHP In 2022

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, twitch-api

I have been unable to get an OAuth token.  I have spent about 4 hours trying.  The various iterations and changes the Twitch API has been through is leaving me unsure and confused.  The Twitch Developers now have a message posted stating V5 API being decommission on February 28th 2022.  I am lost.

This is where I am at right now.  The "code" below is from the **Getting authorization code** [here](https://write.corbpie.com/twitch-api-authentication-with-oauth-using-php/).

```
<?php

    function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
        $curlHeader = [
            'client_id' => '"CLIENT ID"',
            'client_secret' => '"CLIENT SECRET"',
            'code' => '"POST TOKEN"',
            'grant_type' => '"AUTHENTICATION CODE"',
            'redirect_uri' => 'https://rons-home.net'
        ];

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curlHeader);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }

print_r( file_get_contents_curl( 'https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/authorize' ) );
```

Response

```
{"status":400,"message":"missing response type"}
```

Comment: You are currently trying to send what _should_ actually be POST parameters, as HTTP headers instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid curl call to do the Step 3 of user oAuth

Most notably:

- you were trying to pass paramters as a header
- And you have extra `"` littered in your paramerters
- And your grant type if *very* wrong

Substitute the constants as needed.

```php
        $ch = curl_init('https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
            'client_id' => CLIENT_ID,
            'client_secret' => CLIENT_SECRET,
            'code' => $_GET['code'],
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI
        ));

        // fetch the data
        $r = curl_exec($ch);
        // get the information about the result
        $i = curl_getinfo($ch);
        // close the request
        curl_close($ch);
```